# How to auto click div over flash object with delay

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-events

I hope to be clear :)

I'm looking for a way to click automatic a flash object on page load after about 5 seconds.

I have try to put a blank div over the flash, when i click on the div it click also the flash object this is good but I want this do automatic with no user interaction just done by JavaScript on page load this is my code =>

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD html 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
<title>
Newbie at work
</title>

<script>
$("#pipo").trigger("click");

 </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="pipo">
<object width="280" height="280">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.newbies.com/media/swf/player/bobo.swf"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="wmode" value="opaque"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
<embed src="http://www.newbies.com/media/swf/player/bobo.swf" 
width="280" height="280" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
wmode="opaque" 
allowscriptaccess="always" 
allowfullscreen="true" 
movie="http://www.newbies.com/media/swf/player/bobo.swf" >
</embed></object>
</div>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understand your question you need a time out

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(
        function(){
            $("#pipo").trigger("click");
            //optional
            $("#pipo").click();
        }
    ,5000);
});
```

Comment: yes i need it but most of i need made it work the click because at this time it doesn't work at all no click at all :(

Comment: what shoud hapend then you fire click event ?

Comment: i just want that a click on the div start after page load then the flash will be played because i try to click on the div over the flash and it work so i want this done automaticely without the need of real human click, just need to be done by the script.

Comment: try put: $("#pipo").click(); instead of: $("#pipo").trigger("click");

Comment: Hello thanks again but nothing work im sure it's not hard task but i cant solve it i can give 15$ if u can fix it thanks